# Async loop ftp+stream MaxListenersExceededWarning

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I'm trying to get multiples files from a ftp trough an async loop.
Everything is working but i get a warning in the console: MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added to [EventEmitter]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit

I'm using module async, ftp and i'm running node 12.22

```
// ftp connexion managed previously
async.eachOfLimit(list, 1, function(e, i, ecb){

    ftp_client.get(e, function(err, stream){

        if(err || !stream)
        {
             return ecb();
        }
        else
        {
            stream.once('close', function() {
                console.log(" => OK");
                return ecb(null);
            });

            stream.once('error', function() {
                return ecb();
            });

            stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(mypath));
        }
    });


    ftp_client.on("error", function(err){

        return ecb();
    });
    
}, function(err){
   console.log("=> done");
   return callback();
});
```

It display

```
 => OK
 => OK
 => OK
 => OK
 => OK
 => OK
 => OK
 => OK
 => OK
 => OK
 => OK
MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added to [EventEmitter]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
 => OK
 => OK
 => OK
...
```

What can i do to fix that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably caused by this line:

```
 ftp_client.on("error", ...)
```

You're adding a new listener for each iteration of the loop and nothing ever removes it so they build up and then you get the warning.  The purpose of the warning is precisely to detect this type of situation.

You can fix that particular issue by making sure you remove that listener when you're done:

```
// ftp connexion managed previously
async.eachOfLimit(list, 1, function (e, i, ecb) {

    function done(err) {
        // remove error listener so it doesn't build up extra listeners
        ftp_client.off("error", done);
        ecb(err);
    }

    ftp_client.get(e, function (err, stream) {

        if (err || !stream) {
            return done();
        }
        else {
            stream.once('close', function () {
                console.log(" => OK");
                return done(null);
            });

            stream.once('error', done);

            stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(mypath));
        }
    });


    ftp_client.on("error", done);

}, function (err) {
    console.log("=> done");
    return callback();
});
```